# How to paste in a console by using gpm and a touchpad

Tags: touchpad, virtual-console

I would like to use gpm and my touchpad in a console. However,  I don’t know how to simulate a middle click for pasting. I am trying to start gpm in two button mode - “-2  Force two buttons. This means that the middle button, if any, will be taken as it was the right one.” 
But, it affects only the external mouse, not my touchpad.  I copied below my gpm.conf.

```
device=/dev/input/mice
responsiveness=
repeat_type=none
type=exps2
append='-2'
sample_rate=
```

Could someone advise, please?

Comment: gpm (general purpose mouse).
And I am asking about a virtual console, not a terminal.  Cntr-Alt-F1...F6

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, I didn't. Just keeping a 3-button mouse around.